# How can I diagnose my broken X server (Parabola/Arch)?

Tags: xorg, openrc, parabola

I am using Parabola GNU/Linux (based on Arch) on an x86 desktop with an nVidia GTX 1050 GPU. I ran `pacman -Su` yesterday to perform a full system upgrade and it seems to have completely broken my X server. Now, on boot, the display manager (sddm) won't load and it drops into the CLI. I have searched through all the log files I can find (`dmesg`, `Xorg.0.log`, `rc.log` etc.) and I can't find any clues as to what the problem is. I should also mention that I am using OpenRC, rather than systemd.

Interestingly, if I try to load the DE from the terminal with `startx`, I get different issues with Mate and LXDE. With Mate, I get a black screen with a mouse cursor that responds to the mouse. With LXDE, the desktop, panel and background all load up, but I can't see the mouse cursor (although right clicking brings up the context menu).

Any ideas what I can try to diagnose the issue and fix this?

**Update:**

I found the `~/.cache/lxsession/LXDE/run.log` file, which indicated that lxpanel was having an issue with libxml2. I downgraded that library and now LXDE seems to work ok when started with `startx`. However, it doesn't seem to have fixed the issue with Mate.

I have now realized that Mate is actually working, but is experiencing a different issue. When I log in with `startx`, I initially get the black screen w. mouse cursor; however, if I switch to a different virtual terminal (e.g. with `CTL-ALT-F2`) and then switch back again, the whole Mate desktop is there and working.

I believe Mate session errors should be getting posted in `~/.xsession-errors`; however, that file isn't being touched. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

XDM/SDDM seem to still be crashing on boot as well, so I need to figure out what is going wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running `sddm` from the terminal, which indicated issues with two libraries that had been upgraded: `icu` and `libQt5Core`. I downgraded those and it resolved the issue with XDM/SDDM not loading. So, now the system does boot into SDDM again. The login issue with Mate is persisting, so I may ask another question relating specifically to that.

The moral of this story appears to be: use `pacman -Su` at your peril ... :-(